# Baidu Map uses in ionic platform

Tags: dictionary, ionic-framework, baidu

[image]

I added **Baidu Maps** to my **Ionic Platform** app. 
when i clicked baidu static map, the map loaded.
however, after loading the map can not get other region images.

i mean, tears the map.
and zoom is not working. i don't know hot to solve it.
i already tried make new ak key for Android SDK. but same problem arise.
please help me.....

1. index.html : `script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=up......`
2. directive file (it's very simple)

   ```
           var centerLocation = new BMap.Point($scope.hotelDetail.hotelInfo.longitude , $scope.hotelDetail.hotelInfo.latitude);


           var rtMap = new BMap.Map($element[0]);

           rtMap.centerAndZoom(new BMap.Point(centerLocation.lng, centerLocation.lat),12);
           rtMap.addControl(new BMap.OverviewMapControl());
           rtMap.addControl(new BMap.ScaleControl());
           rtMap.addControl(new BMap.NavigationControl());

           rtMap.enableAutoResize();
           rtMap.enableScrollWheelZoom(true);
           rtMap.enableDoubleClickZoom();
           rtMap.enableDragging(true);

           var myGeo  = new BMap.Geocoder();

           myGeo.getPoint($scope.hotelDetail.hotelInfo.addressLn, function(point) {

               if(point) {
                   rtMap.centerAndZoom(point, 16);
                   rtMap.addOverlay(new BMap.Marker(point));
               }
               $ionicLoading.hide();
           }, "");
   ```

Comment: solved it~!! changed css.

Comment: can't you answer your own question, for the world to see how you fixed it?